# Efficient way to solve a set of linear equations $Ax=b$ when $A$ is sparse and some elements of $b$ are equal to zero

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I have a set of linear equations, $Ax=b$. And about half of the elements in the right-hand side (vector $b$) are equal to zero. My system matrix $A$ is a sparse complex matrix. And $A$ is in the size range of $2000 \times 2000$.
I am currently using LU decomposition to solve the system.

Is there a way that I can take both advantages of sparsity and the zero elements in $b$ when solving the set of equations?

Comment: When solving the triangle systems, you can certainly use the sparseness of $b$. Davis' book on sparse matrix methods is one reference.

Comment: when you say LU, do you mean a dense LU, or a sparse LU solver?

Comment: Thanks @vibe. I'll refer this book.

Comment: @Thijs Steel, It would be great if I can use a sparse LU solver and still get the advantage of the sparsity of b.

Comment: In my experience, unless the dimensions of $b$ are much larger than 2000, sparse right hand sides aren't any faster in practice when solving linear systems. The sparsity of $A$, however, is almost always worth investigating. Most sparse solvers I have encountered won't accept a sparse right hand side, or will just create a temporary dense version of it for the calculations. 

For instance, Matlab's LU solver uses UMFPACK (written by Davis as mentioned by @vibe), which does not support sparse right hand sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem as stated is not quite restrictive enough to meaningfully exploit. For any "interesting" sparse matrix $\mathbf A$, even if the forcing data $\mathbf b$ is sparse, the solution data $\mathbf x$ will still be fully populated/dense.

However, there is a nearby problem that does have exploitable structure: if $\mathbf b$ is sparse, and you only care about a subset of the entries of $\mathbf x$, then it is possible to find them using less time/space than the naive approach (in which you compute all of $\mathbf x$ and then sift out the ones you want).

Unfortunately this algorithm is not commonplace, but I can at least point you to my own [implementation](http://www.myracore.com/myramath/doc/html/multifrontal2_tutorial.html#multifrontal2_tut4). I think MUMPS might have a similar capability, their names pop up often when you look for these sorts of tricks (sparsity-exploiting backsolves). The earliest mention of this idea that I have found is in a [thesis](https://oatao.univ-toulouse.fr/7786/1/slavova.pdf) by T. Slavova (who was advised by the MUMPS team).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm interested in only a subset of x corresponds to the non-zero elements of 'b'.
I'll refer the references you mentioned.